# Enabling & disabling form's field based on the choice of radio button & select option together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

[image]

In the above form, when the users choose `No` radio button of `Want it?` field the following select menu of `If yes, how?` field & text input area of `Address` field should be disabled.

If the users choose `Yes` both the following fields should be enabled where users shall have the preference to choose delivery method in the selection menu of `If yes, how?` field which are:

`home_delivery`

`pos_delivery`

If the users select `pos_delivery` the text input area of `Address` field should be disabled.

The html & jQuery codes are as following:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Want it?</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="choose" id="yes" value="Yes" />Yes</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="choose" id="no" value="No" />No</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>If yes, how?</td>
<td>
<select name="delivery_method" id="delivery_method">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select Delivery Method</option>
<option value="home_delivery">Home Delivery</option>
<option value="pos_delivery">Point of Sale Delivery</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address:</td>
<td><input name="address" id="address" type="text" value="" size="30" />
</td>
</tr>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('input[name="choose"]').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).val() === 'Yes') {
        $('#delivery_method,#address').removeProp("disabled");
    }else{
        $('#delivery_method,#address').prop("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});disabled
});
</script>
</script>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#address').attr('disabled','disabled');        
$('select[name="delivery_method"]').on('change',function(){
var  option = $(this).val();
    if(option === "home_delivery"){           
    $('#address').removeAttr('disabled');          
     }else{
     $('#address').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
    }  
  });
});
</script>
```

The following blocks of jQuery code serve the purpose individually but when these are combined together, it seems that the following two blocks of jQuery code are conflicting with each other.

How can I combined these two block of code together in this case?

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a fiddle account. If you post it there, it may be helpful for the users.

Comment: @SilentPond You don't need any account to create a jsFiddle

Comment: you don't need a fiddle account to create a fiddle, just click here [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/) and click save, then copy the link and paste it in here...

Comment: @A. Wolff , let me check.

Comment: @A. Wolff & webeno, it's done. Fiddle url is  http://jsfiddle.net/5XYGQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this...

```
$('#delivery_method,#address').removeProp("disabled", "disabled");
```

...with this...

```
$('#delivery_method,#address').prop("disabled", false);
```

Additionally you somehow left a `disabled` function or statement there for some reason:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('input[name="choose"]').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).val() === 'Yes') {
            $('#delivery_method,#address').prop("disabled", false);
        }else{
           $('#delivery_method,#address').prop("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });disabled /* <-- this one */
});
```

...just remove that and you should be good to go.

**EDITED:** A little explanation: `removeProp` takes one property only, so you either use that properly...

```
$('#delivery_method,#address').removeProp("disabled");
```

... or use `prop` to do the same, as shown above.

**[Here is a fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s4g7G/)**

Comment: I pointed out a negligible problem later on the code loses it's functionality when options are selected like `Yes->Point of Sales->No->Yes. Any comment or resolution? Thanks,

Comment: webeno , I got the reference of `});disabled /* <-- this one */` from http://jsfiddle.net/94PR5/. I'm an expert in `html & css` when these are about `PHP` & `jQuery` I like to play with the logic and develop new code based on existing code.